# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) - elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I was trying to uninstall elasticsearch and reinstall it. when I remove it with below command it was showing following error.

```
$ apt-get --purge autoremove elasticsearch

Reading package lists... Done<br/>
Building dependency tree<br/>
Reading state information... Done<br/>
The following packages will be REMOVED:<br/>
elasticsearch*<br/>
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.<br/>
After this operation, 30.5 MB disk space will be freed.<br/>
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y<br/>
(Reading database ... 37152 files and directories currently installed.)<br/>
Removing elasticsearch (2.4.5) ...<br/>
Stopping elasticsearch service...Failed to issue method call: Unit elasticsearch.service not loaded.<br/>
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--purge):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
NOT starting on installation, please execute the following statements to configure elasticsearch service to start automatically using systemd<br/>

sudo systemctl daemon-reload<br/>
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service<br/>
You can start elasticsearch service by executing<br/>

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service<br/>
Errors were encountered while processing:<br/>
** elasticsearch**<br/>
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)<br/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same error with elasticsearch was resolved by install jre.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by this way in Ubuntu 20.04

1. java -version
2. sudo gedit /etc/environment
3. In the file, you have to
   mention the path as given below JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-**(your
   java version maybe 11/14/etc)**-openjdk-amd64"
4. echo $JAVA_HOME